# Is it a safe cross-browser solution to show/hide optgroup using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, select, cross-browser, hide, optgroup

I know that some years ago we couldn't safely show/hide optgroups with Javascript

Can we now write this kind of code without any troubles?

```
$("select[name='mySelect']").children("optgroup[label='toto']").hide();
```

If this code is not cross-browser I found [this small plugin](https://gist.github.com/robcowie/2267793) which should do the job, but if a simple show/hide is now possible it's a more simple solution.

Comment: All depends on your browser support needs.

Comment: Let's say all "modern browsers" - less than 2 years old